# How to ssh into the cpanel of my hosting server?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ssh-keys

I want to ssh into my domain's cpanel hosted on a linux server ?
I'm planning to use Ubuntu's terminal as my ssh client.
my hosting service provide is squarebrothers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure they even allow SSH? This is an old post (07 Nov 2005) from them but they state they don't here:

http://www.support.squarebrothers.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=3